# delete element in queue in java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

Write the method public staticvoid remove(Queueq, int[] pos, int k), which removes all the elements of q located at the positions indicated in pos (k is the size of pos). Assume that pos is sorted in increasing order with no duplicates and contains only valid positions.The numbering of the positions starts from 0 at the head. The method must run in O(n), where n is the size of q (not O(kn)).
Example : If q : A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H and pos : 1,2,5, then after calling remove(q, pos, 3), q becomes A, D, E, G, H.

Comment: Are you allowed to use extra space?

Comment: you should use linked list for implementation, you don't need any extra space for this.

Comment: This is a homework question.

Comment: [students-with-homework-problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy, if you implement the Queue using any LinkedList. 
As you tagged this question as "java", you might use `java.util.ArrayList`

Looks like, it is homework question,

Comment: A `java.util.ArrayList` is not a linked list.